# Determine Swift object type from Any Object in a more Swifty way

Tags: swift, types

I have a dictionary of `[String:Any]` and when i load from `UserDefaults` I get back a `Date` object, but from Firebase I get back a `Timestamp` object.

Surely there is a my Swifty way to write this code ?

```
var correctDate:Date!

if let t = dictionary[key.timestamp] as? Timestamp {
    print("as Timestamp")
    correctDate = t.dateValue()
}
else if let t = dictionary[key.timestamp] as? Date {
    print("as Date")
    correctDate = t
}
else {
    fatalError("no date object found")
}

print(correctDate)
```

Comment: Note that you don't need an implicitly unwrapped optional here, and even can make the variable constant: `let correctDate: Date`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is a `switch` more Swifty?:

```
switch dictionary[key.timestamp] {
case let timestamp as Timestamp:
    print("as TimeStamp")
    correctDate = timestamp.dateValue()
case let date as Date:
    print("as Date")
    correctDate = date
default:
    fatalError("no date object found")
}
```

---

**Use a protocol**

You have two objects which both represent *date objects*. Why not unify them with a protocol and give them a common interface?

Use a protocol to create a `DateObject` that both `Date` and `Timestamp` adopt:

```
protocol DateObject {
    var date: Date { get }
}

extension Date: DateObject {
    var date: Date { return self }
}

extension Timestamp: DateObject {
    var date: Date { return self.dateValue() }
}

// Added this extension for NSDate after comments
// indicated that NSDate objects were coming back
// from UserDefaults
extension NSDate: DateObject {
    var date: Date { return self as Date }
}

if let date = (dictionary[key.timestamp] as? DateObject)?.date {
    print("has date")
    correctDate = date
} else {
    fatalError("no date object found")
}
```

Comment: @AhmadF, tedious is in the eye of the beholder.  I see that he has two different objects that represent the same concept: a date object.  You can see that by his fatal error message "no date object found". Unifying them with a protocol makes sense.  Then you could do other things like have an array of `DateObject`s and put `Date`s and `Timestamp`s in them.  It's useful for more than just *checking the type*.

Comment: While it works with test data, it wont work from data from UserDefaults, it fails to create the DataObject itself. I tried adding a NSDate extension, but this still failed but at it seems to attempt to the conversion - throwing the error Could not cast value of type '__NSDate'

Comment: @DogCoffee, what did you try for the `NSDate` extension? `extension NSDate: DateObject { var date: Date { return (self as Date) } }` seems to work.

Comment: perfect thanks - I wrote my extension wrong - I used { return self.date } which failed.

Answer (score 1):

By using `??` [Nil-Coalescing operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID72), you could:

```
let timeStamp = dictionary[key.timestamp] as? Timestamp
let date = dictionary[key.timestamp] as? Date

if let correctDate = timeStamp?.dateValue() ?? date {
    print(correctDate)
} else {
    fatalError("no date object found")
}
```

Assuming that `timeStamp.dateValue()` returns `Date` type.

Comment: Because `timeStamp` is optional, you have to use optional chainig: `timeStamp?.dateValue()`